# Error caused by changing IOS project name xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I was developing an IOS app on Xcode. I used jaloo as the project name at the beginning and I changed it to Jaloo. When I build it, it fails with the error:

Apple Mach-O linker Error

"ld: file not found: /Users/yangyuan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Jaloo-evdaocdennammiajxpinsodrluhl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/jaloo.app/jaloo

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"

I don't know how to fix this then I changed the name back to jaloo. The error disappears but all the names in the build settings changed to jaloo.temp_caseinsensitive_rename.temp_caseinsensitive_rename.temp_caseinsensitive_rename.temp_caseinsensitive_rename which is quiet annoying. I read through some similar posts but the solutions don't work for me. Anyone have ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select Manage Scheme

[image]

Unchecked All the Show And Delete All the Scheme by Pressing Minus Sign.

[image]

After Deleting All The Scheme, Select Project-->Select Target-->Build Setting

Change the Product Name and also delete the Test in Target
[image]

Now Select New Scheme and Press OK

[image]

[image]

and run the app.

Answer (score 0):

Select Project -> Target -> Select Hide or show utilities->Identity and type-> Name  and put your name here.Press Enter. then you will prompt "Rename project Content items" Select rename -> Enable -> ok. if you still have error then delete test file below target.hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

This is a confusing answer, as the rename feature is *almost* so complete. I have a complex project that i wanted to test, so i duplicated, renamed it to ensure no impact on other resources, and all except this last linker issue resolved. I did not want to delete my schemes as they are there for good reason (testing while the app is off for example) ...

Since i don't use the stock testing project, i wiped it, and it compiles fine, but the lingering issue is unusual.

I thought to drop this here in case others have the same trouble, and like me, are not using the Tests project.